# How can I force the use of a specific branch on a git submodule when commiting and pushing changes in a superproject?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to do this, so I can enforce release branches in submodules when pushing a release branch in the superproject

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Submodule branch names only matter if and when you're doing actual work in that submodule, and even then, only so that you can easily `git push` from that submodule.  Otherwise, only the actual raw hash ID inside the submodule matters.  Git will usually keep the submodule set up with a "detached HEAD".  While you can—in newer versions of Git—store a branch name to go with the submodule, Git really does not ever *use* that name when working in the superproject.  It just uses commit hash IDs.

You *can* get the superproject to `git checkout` a (detached HEAD) commit in a submodule using a name based on names in the upstream of that submodule.  This is occasionally useful when *you* don't work on the submodule, but someone else does: you may want to pick up their latest commit, see if it works with your project, and if so, switch your project to use their latest commit.  Here, the branch name is a little bit useful because `git submodule update --remote` can use it to have your submodule clone call up *their* Git, see their Git's branch names, and obtain for you the hash ID.  But this is really aimed at a development process, not a release process.

#### Long

The short answer is mostly "you can't do that directly", but also mostly "it doesn't matter".

The fact is that to a superproject, even the *existence* of branches in a submodule is irrelevant, much less what those branch names might be and what their corresponding hash IDs might be.  **Each commit in the superproject records the raw hash ID of the commit that is to be used in the submodule.**

Let's make this example a little more concrete.  Suppose we have a project named **P**.  This repository—let's call it **RepoP**—has some commits in it.  This repository has some branch names, such as `master`, `feature/f`, and perhaps `release/v1` and the like.  It may also have tag names, such as `v1.0` which is the specific release within branch `release/v1` that represents version 1.0.

Each of these names—`master`, `feature/f`, `v1.0`, and so on—names *one specific commit* in RepoP.  The difference between a *branch* name and a *tag* name is that the branch name moves over time: today, `master` might be commit `a123456...`, and tomorrow it might be `b789abc...` instead.  A tag name should never change: it always represents the same commit.

When you do a `git checkout` within RepoP, regardless of whether you use a branch name or a tag name or just a raw commit hash, Git first figures out *which commit this is*.  That is, Git finds the actual hash ID of the target commit.  Git then extracts that commit—all of the files in its snapshot—into Git's index / staging-area and into the work-tree for RepoP.

If this commit has some submodules, those go into the index too.  They do not go into the work-tree—not yet!  But Git will make an empty directory into which they will go, when it needs to do that (which is in just a moment).

Let's say that you used a name that chose commit `a123456...` in RepoP.  Let's say further that commit `a123456...` calls for two submodules, to be extracted into `path/to/s1` and `s2` (no leading directory path, just `./s2`) respectively.  In commit `a123456`, you will find two entities that Git calls *gitlinks:* they hold `path/to/s1` and a raw hash ID, and `s2` and a second raw hash ID.  Git reads all the gitlinks into the index, too, so that they're ready to be saved forever in the *next* commit you make.

Let's say that the gitlink for `path/to/s1` has hash ID `5100000...` and the gitlink for `s2` has hash ID `5200000...`.  (These are pretty unlikely, but no less unlikely than `a123456...` or `a6496b61...` or whatever.  The fact is, if this commit calls for these two submodules, there will be two hash IDs, whatever they are.)

Now that commit `a123456` is in your work-tree, *now* Git can go about filling in the submodules.  You may need to run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

manually, at this point, to make it do everything, or you may have done your `git checkout` with options that make Git do this automatically, but one way or another, you now instruct Git to fill in the submodules.

Git will now *enter the directory `path/to/s1`*, clone the submodule repository if necessary, and then run:

```
git checkout 5100000...
```

to get *that specific commit* checked out in the submodule's subdirectory, `path/to/s1`.  (Remember, we said that the gitlink entry for `path/to/s1` that is now in your index says *use commit `510000...` with this commit*.  So that's what Git does.)

Git will enter the subdirectory `s2`, clone the submodule if needed, and run:

```
git checkout 5200000...
```

to get *that specific commit* checked out in the submodule's subdirectory `s2`.

**Note that the path and the commit hash ID came out of the superproject.**  Git never did look at *any* branch name in the submodules.  The submodules' branch names simply don't matter.<sup>1</sup>

Git puts each submodule repository into a *detached HEAD* state, using the commit hash IDs stored in the *superproject*.  **You only need to store the correct hash IDs into the superproject.**  Well, that is, you only need to do that *and* make sure that those commits exist *in* the submodules when the submodules get cloned.

---

<sup>1</sup>Except, that is, during the original `git clone` of this submodule: Git needs to *find* commits, and to find commits, Git needs some names.  This is because the hash IDs look totally random.  There's no way to tell which commits are the *newest* ones, unless you have a branch name like `release/1.0` that holds the newest hash ID for the `release/1.0` branch.

---

#### So when *do* submodule branch names matter?

Let's say you're about to do some work on project P, in your RepoP work-tree.

The work you need to do involves fixing a bug, or adding a feature, to submodule `s2`.  So, in this window or in another one or whatever, you enter `s2`.

You are now in the submodule Git repository.  `git status` shows that you have a *detached HEAD*, because the superproject Git told the submodule Git: *check out commit `5200000...` as a detached HEAD*, and it did.

You can now modify code and make commits, but if you do so, they will simply be on this detached HEAD.  It will be hard to push them to some other Git.  So *now* you may wish to get onto a branch.

Newer versions of Git allow you to have the superproject Git direct the submodule Git to check out a branch by name.  **You must issue a command at this point in the superproject to make it do this.**<sup>2</sup>  But if you're going to do some work inside `s2` yourself, you can just issue a simple `git checkout` command inside `s2`, while working on the submodule:

```
git checkout release/1.0
```

for instance.  Now you can do your work as usual and commit, which will make the new commit change the hash ID stored in the submodule's branch name `release/1.0`.  You can then `git push` the resulting commit to the submodule's `origin` to add it to *that* repository's `release/1.0` as well.

Let's say, just for concreteness, that this new commit was somehow assigned hash ID `5200001...` when you made it.  Now that your new commit, with your new feature, exists in the submodule and has been pushed to `origin`, you simply go back to the superproject and use `git add` to update the index / staging-area in the superproject Git:

```
git add s2
```

The *next* commit you make in RepoP will say: *When using this commit, tell the Git for submodule `s2` to check out commit `5200001...`.*  Anyone *using* the new commit uses it by its detached-HEAD raw hash ID.  The branch name is irrelevant to the superproject.  You just needed to use it while *working* in the submodule, so that you could push the new commit to `origin`, so that everyone who clones the submodule will get commit `5200001...` too.

---

<sup>2</sup>I believe newer versions of Git are getting some fancier controls here, which might make your work slightly easier, especially if there are multiple submodules that require working-in.  But really, how much easier is it to do `git submodule newsubcommand release/1.0` followed by `cd s2` followed by doing your work, vs `cd s2` followed by `git checkout release/1.0` followed by doing your work?